# Rspec - verifying a spy was called with a certain block

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I'm using Discord's webhook Ruby library, so my code looks like this:

```
client = Discordrb::Webhooks::Client.new(url: WEBHOOK_URL)
client.execute do |builder|
  builder.content = 'Hello world!'
end
```

In my test, I've injected an `instance_spy` as the `client` and would like to verify that I've passed along the correct value (`'Hello world!'` in this case) to the builder. I'm familiar with how to use `expect(...).to have_received(...).with(...)`, but in this case, how would I verify it?

Comment: Could you please share the relevant test code for this? *"I've injected an `instance_spy` as the `client`"* -- I wouldn't want to make potentially false assumptions about the existing spec setup.

Comment: You can't actually verify that a method is called with "a certain block" as blocks are anomynous. Did you mean within a block? What you can do is stub the `execute` method - or use for example dependency injection so that you can make it yield a spy. It still smells like your poking way to far into the internals though instead of testing the behavior.